# How to create a half filled circle in tasks?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tasks

I'm trying to make the last circle half filled like how \skill{Office}{4.5} work. Here's my try:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style
\usepackage[left=0.4 in,top=0.4in,right=0.4 in,bottom=0.4in]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{rSection}{Skills} \vspace{1em}
\begin{tasks}[style=itemize, column-sep=-35mm, label-align=center, label-offset={2mm}, label-width={2mm}, item-indent={5mm}](3)%

\task[] \textnormal{MATLAB}
\tikz\draw[black,fill=black] (0,0) circle (.5ex);
\tikz\draw[black,fill=black] (0,0) circle (.5ex);
\tikz\draw[black,fill=black] (0,0) circle (.5ex);
\tikz\draw[black,fill=black] (0,0) circle (.5ex);
\tikz\draw[black,fill=black] (0,0) circle (.5ex);

\end{tasks}


\end{rSection}
```

How can I do that here?

Comment: Please, provide all needed information and also a complete code. What's your "custom resume class style"? What's `\skill{Office}{4.5}`? Is `\end{document}` the only missing part of your code?

Comment: You can probably adapt either https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482469/graphics-to-represent-a-loading-bar-for-language-skills-in-a-cv-fraction-value or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583089/ to your resume class.